# Stuck in something: How to write coordinates in one number?

Tags: coordinate-systems, polar-coordinates, binary, binary-operations

I have a X, Y coordinate system which starts from 0 and ends in 255 on each axis. Thus, I can fit 65,025 numbers in it. Imagine each number as a pixel, so I have 65,0250 pixels in my coordinate system.

If I pick any random point here, I need to present its X and Y numbers to the computer, so it can detect its position. My problem is that I only have less than 12 bits to save this coordinate number (both X and Y). As you may know, every bit holds only 0s and 1s as integers from 2^0 to 2^8. There are some pixels whose coordinates can be presented in two digits (such as X=55 and Y=30). 55 in binary is equal to 110111 and can be fit in 6 bits, and 30 in binary is equal to 11110 and can be fit in 5 bits. So the coordinates X=55 and Y=30 can be fit into 11 bits altogether.

But the problem is that the majority of pixels (as also visible in the photo) need 3-digit numbers for each X and Y coordinates, thus requiring 16 bits of binary in order to store their positions. For example, the farthest pixel from 0, 0 is the pixel with the coordinates X=255 and Y=255. Each 255 takes 8 bits in binary (11111111), so saving the coordinates of that pixel (and many other pixels) consume 16 bits of binary space. I only have less than 12 bits to do it.

Is there any way to write the position of each pixel in less than 12 bits? I also welcome any ideas about any alternative ways that I can show the position of these pixels (such as polar equations, Archimedean Spiral, Fermat's Spiral, etc.).

I'm stuck here and any help would do great favor to me. Thank you.

[image]
Number of pixels with equivalent amounts of bits to save their positions in an X, Y coordinate system.

Comment: It seems impossible since there are $2^{16}$ points and you have enough space to store one number from $2^{12}$, so any map will not be injective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to hold them all of them it is never possible, 16 bits of pure information cannot be absolutely held in 12 bits.

It can be possible if you accept 12 bits in mean on a huge number of data (it depends on your exact number distribution but if your integers are mainly small it will work) and it is achievable through compression, I encourage you to see **Huffman coding**.

But in full generality you cannot ensure that every coordinate pair will be held in 12bits. All you can have is 12 bits in mean on a large set of data.

Comment: Thank you for introducing the Huffman coding method to me. I knew about it before, but I had never thought it could be used for compressing the coordinates, until you wrote about it. I checked the Huffman coding articles, but still I'm not sure how to write the coordinates in it. I'm not sure how I can, for example, compress X=230 and Y=155 using Huffman algorithm that consumes less than 16 bits of binary space.

Answer (score 0):

$256^2 = 65536 > 4096 = 2^{12}$, so no, you cannot associate to each of the $65536$ pixels a unique number that takes no more than $12$ bits of storage.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. Can I distribute these coordinates on an Archimedean Spiral (or any other Spiral or other shape) in a way that each point can be represented by only one coordinate? For example, I know that the distance of any point on the Archimedean Spiral is equal to the angle it forms with the line crossing horizontally from the center of the Spiral. So, this means that if I pick a point on the Spiral, I can show it with one number. Problem is distributing those numbers over the Spiral, so that the distance from the center would be a real number (not floating numbers).

Comment: Whatever method you come up with, you will never represent $65536$ distinct points using only $4096$ distinct labels. Anything you do will require you to associate some of the points to the same label. If you evenly distribute things, then since $256^2/2^{12}=2^4=16$, you need to associate $16$ pixels to every $12$-bit sequence. Perhaps the most uniform way to do this would be to divide your $256\times 256$ grid into $4 \times 4$ sub-squares and give all pixels in each sub-square the same label.

Comment: You would have $64$ squares across and $64$ squares up-and-down, and both of these coordinates only take $6$ bits to store, so you could store both in $12$ bits. The catch is, now you can't go backward. For instance, if you are told your pixel is in the third square from the left in the topmost row, its $x$-coordinate could be $8,9,10,11$ and it's $y$-coordinate could be $252,253,254,255$.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. If we know that there's almost no way of fitting 65,536 distinct points using 4096 distinct lables, so there must be a way of presenting 65,536 points in a grid having 16 million pixels. I can increase the size of the grid, so that all 65,536 points would easily fit in and even be repeated in the very large grid containing millions of points. The problem is how to do it in a way that I can present coordinates of any given point with less digits.

Comment: I also have a question about Huffman coding. If we have a binary file at the end as the output which can be converted to this text: 256.240 100.42 55.33 45.59 etc, with each number as X or Y, separated by a dot, will it be able to compress this or its binary equivalent (0s and 1s only) largely using the Huffman coding?

Comment: I don't know anything about Huffman coding. You'll have to ask someone else.